# se puede tener whatsapp web en un iframe html?

Tags: iframe, whatsapp-web

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y me preguntaba si alguien ha intentado integrar WhatsApp Web dentro de un iframe. He estado investigando al respecto, pero no he encontrado información clara al respecto.

Me gustaría saber si alguien ha tenido éxito con esta integración y, en caso afirmativo, ¿podrían compartir algunos consejos o puntos clave que hayan encontrado durante el proceso?

He intentado , pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito. Agradecería cualquier orientación o experiencia que puedan compartir.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tal vez con un proxy???